# Symfony2 and javascript - show/hide()

Tags: jquery, symfony

In my web app I want checkbox to control display or not table column. I had put jquery-2.1.1.js file in ROOT_OF_WEBAPP/WEB/JS/. I need code for show()/hide() column and how include that .js file in current twig. This don't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("jmbg_ch").click(function(event) {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                $(".jmbg_column").show();
            else
                $(".jmbg_column").hide();
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your jQuery selector `$("jmbg_ch")`. If you need to bind `click` action to the element with id `jmbg_ch` you need to use sharp symbol: `$("#jmbg_ch")`.

Also it is not good to place your js in the `web/js` folder. You can put it in `Resources/public/js` folder of your bundle. Then you just need to run `php app/console assets:install --symlink` and all your assets from `Resources/public/js` will be available under `web/bundles/yourbundlename/js`.